# Set multer properties inside an express route

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Instead of attaching `multer` to the entire express `app`, i am trying to include it just for specific routes, which is better since you will be preventing uploads to every route handling `post`.

Problem is, i am unable to set it properties inside a route.

```
var router = require('express').Router(),
multer = require('multer');

router.post('/uploads', function (req, res, next) {
   multer({
     dest: req.app.get('cfg').uploads.dir
   });

   console.log(req.files); process.exit();

});
```

Here, `req.files` is undefined.

The same thing happens if i put multer in a seperate middleware and attach it to the above route.

```
function initMulter(req, res, next) {
    multer({
     dest: req.app.get('cfg').uploads.dir
   });

   next();
}

 router.post('/uploads', initMulter, function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.files); process.exit();

});
```

Also in this case, `req.files` is `undefined`.

Is there something really wrong that i am doing or should i start blaming the beer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multer is it's own middleware.

You can add it to a route via:

```
router.post('/uploads', multer({
     dest: './my/destination' //req.app.get('cfg').uploads.dir
}), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files);
    process.exit();
});
```

Though you're going to have to find another way to access your config.

One way would be to pass the config or `app` through an export function.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    router.post('/uploads', multer({
         dest: config.uploads.dir
    }), function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.files);
        process.exit();
    });
    return router;
});
```

Then when you're requiring,

```
var route = require('./route')(app.get('cfg'));
```

Comment: Any ideas how should i go about do that?

Comment: @SwarajGiri I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: That's too much beating around the bush just to have a configurable dest. Might be worth it to give the multer guys a knock.